# Using URL helpers from the console in Ruby on Rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to use URL helpers in a 2.3.11 Ruby on Rails application, but I'm facing many problems with whatever the solution I try...

I've read a lot of "solutions" like including `include ActionController::UrlWriter` before trying to get a path, but I get the same error every time:

```
>> app.users_path
NameError: undefined method `new_suggestion_path' for class `ActionController::Integration::Session'
```

I can't find the problem with this. I have a "suggestions" controller and a "new" action on it... Is there any other way to fix this and get a URL from console and/or [Rake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_(software))?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using url helpers in the console. You can run `rake routes` from the root of your Rails app to see all available routes.

Comment: If this is a serious application, I suggest trying to upgrade it. Rails 2 is very old.

Comment: It's too big to consider an upgrade @JustinWood.

Comment: I want to get all routes from the console to visit and parse every url with nokogiri @Iceman

Answer (score 3):

You need to have resource routes defined for the named routes you are trying to access.

To make *suggestion* paths available in Rails 2.3, add a resource route `config/routes.rb`:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :suggestions
end
```

That will define the following routes:

```
     suggestions GET    /suggestions(.:format)          {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"index"}
                 POST   /suggestions(.:format)          {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"create"}
  new_suggestion GET    /suggestions/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"new"}
 edit_suggestion GET    /suggestions/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"edit"}
      suggestion GET    /suggestions/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"show"}
                 PUT    /suggestions/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"update"}
                 DELETE /suggestions/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"suggestions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Now you can use those routes in the console:

```
>> app.new_suggestion_path
=> "/suggestions/new"
>>
```

Comment: I already have this route: map.resources :suggestions,:only => [:new, :create]